# How can I ensure that a table is never wider than its containing div?

Tags: html, css

I have a div which contains a table, which has another div with dynamically changing text.
The div has styles

```
overflow: hidden;
white-space: nowrap;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

so I expect when the text is wider than the div it will show "..." at the end, but in real, the table width will be larger than the container div, which is really weird.

If I set the cell max-width in px or pt, which contains the div with the text, then working fine, but that's not an option.

How can set the table to follow the width of the container div and never be larger than that?

Some sample code is [in a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DrUrV/1/).

Comment: Do you need all the tables?

Comment: It's a generated code from an other app, that's why so much table, but I tried only with one table and the result is the same.

Comment: Why isn't suddenly SO doesn't allow pasting of jsFiddle links?

Comment: @PraveenKumar To keep people from posting: "I have a problem with <jsFiddle link>. How do I fix it?" and getting closed as "Too localized". [Now code must be supplied alongside the fiddle link.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149890/prevent-posts-with-links-to-jsfiddle-and-no-code)

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the `#c121` div's width unless you insist of having it.

Tables conform only to their content, not their wrappers.

Since it's generated markup, are you able of adding some `class` or `properties` on the elements?

Comment: I need that width, in the application it's used as a part of a custom selectlist component and the user can control the width of that component that's why I want to use the `text-overflow` property. And yes, I can add extra code to the elements during generation.